# Text box will not go to bottom of Div. Position absolute doesn't work

Tags: html, css, parallax

Hi I'm trying to create a parallax scrolling effect for my website.  It partially works.  However I'm trying to position a text box to stay at the bottom of a section  i.e #slide-2.  For some reason...it just stays on top of Div..rather than being positioned right in the bottom.  I've tried

```
bottom:0;
```

and

```
position: absolute;
```

But position absolute makes the parallax effect not work.

[image]

```
#slide-2 .bcg {background-image:url("http://oilguru.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Refinery-Sunset-Scenic-for-Oil-Guru-Recruitment-e1339505787369.jpg");
position: relative;
}

 slide-2 .hsContent {
        bottom: 0px;
        position: relative;
}


slide-2 .hscontainer {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
}

  #slide-2 h2 {
                 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
                bottom: 0;
                /* top: 20%;*/
                color: #ffffff;
                  font-size: 15px;
                line-height: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
                <section id="slide-2" class="homeSlide">


   <div class="bcg"
        data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;"
        data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;"
        data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100px;"
        data-anchor-target="#slide-2"
    >





<h2>Text box area
</h2>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Show your HTML structure, please. Better, put it in a http://jsfiddle.net with colored boxes.

Comment: `position:relative` moves an element in regard to the position it would have in normal flow. So by combining that with `bottom:0` you are only telling the element to have it’s bottom corner be offset by zero pixels from where it already **is** … Your question title was about `position:absolute`, but you are not using that anywhere in the CSS shown.

Comment: I know I'm not using Position:absolute.  I took it off.

I stated that when I use it...it stops the parallax effect from not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set height of the slide container:

```
#slide-2 .bcg {
    background-image:url("http://oilguru.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Refinery-Sunset-Scenic-for-Oil-Guru-Recruitment-e1339505787369.jpg");
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
}
```

Then use absolute positioning for the textbox area:

```
#slide-2 h2 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpspwcku/